# Confirm beforeunload ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I need to confirm with ajax before leave the page but with `confirm('message')` I have a bug

```
$( window ).on( "beforeunload", function(){
    confirm('message');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: 'page.php',
        success: function(dat) {
            alert(dat);
        }
    });
});
```

You have a idea for confirm before ajax?

Comment: please add more detail of problem, btw if you don't test the return value of confirm the confirm its useless

Comment: this is just not a reliable way to do server communications, do it long before unload

Answer (score 0):

confirm() returns a boolean. You need to check it's value before continuing.

```
if(confirm("Do you want to AJAX something?") {
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: 'page.php',
            success: function(dat) {
                alert(dat);
            }
        }); 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do all this beforeUnload, though. I think that the confirm dialog will show up, but the AJAX won't finish before the page is unloaded.

Comment: Its work but in `$( window ).on( "beforeunload", function(){` not working why please ?

Comment: Please see answer posted by @BradChristie. In short: you can't do that inside a beforeunload.